# Groovy regex match without inclusion

Tags: regex, groovy

I need get each block Foo from string below. I use a regular expression for this. Code is presented below. But due to part `($|(  ..F))` of regex I get only `Foo[1]` and `Foo[3]`. How can I get each `Foo` block with regex?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher

String test = '''  ..Foo[1]dsfsdf
  ...........sfsdfdsfsdfsdf
  ..............sdfffffffffsd
  ..................sdffffffffffffffff
  ..Foo[2]dsfsdf
  ...........sfsdfdsfsdfsdf
  ..............sdfffffffffsd
  ..................sdffffffffffffffff
  ..Foo[3]dsfsdf
  ...........sfsdfdsfsdfsdf
  ..............sdfffffffffsd
  ..................sdffffffffffffffff
  ..Foo[4]dsfsdf
  ...........sfsdfdsfsdfsdf
  ..............sdfffffffffsd
  ..................sdffffffffffffffff'''

Matcher m = test =~ /(Foo\[[0-9]{1,6}\][\s\S]*?)($|(  ..F))/
m.find();
//after this m.count equals 2 and contains only Foo[1] and Foo[3], but I need 4 with all Foo's
```

Comment: This is not clear to me

Comment: @YassinHajaj why? Groovy syntaxis? Java equivalent: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Foo\[[0-9]{1,6}\][\s\S]*?)($|(  ..F))"); Matcher m = p.matcher(test); m.find()

Comment: Ok I did not notice it was groovy. sorry.

Comment: instead of trying to match all blocks, split on `\s*\.\.(?=Foo\[)` and exclude the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the `($|(  ..F))` non-consuming by turning it into a [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) by adding `?=` after the opening `(` (and escape the dots so that they could match literal dots):

```
(Foo\[[0-9]{1,6}\][\s\S]*?)(?=$|  \.\.F)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF0kY4/1)

Comment: Note that lazy matching is not the best way to match very long chunks of text, you can unroll this pattern as [`(Foo\[[0-9]{1,6}\][^ ]*(?: (?! \.\.F)[^ ]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/sF0kY4/2). Compare the number of steps required in the green box. 222 vs. 1787. `[^ ]` can be replaced with `\S` and a space - with `\s`.